# Where UUID is Displayed in android Device?

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I get the Device UUID using **cordova** (device.uuid) now I'm not able to see where UUID is actually stored in my Android Device. I require to let the user get to know that where is actually UUID is Displayed in Android Device?

Or any other way to get the Device Unique id for Android as well as iOS using single code and can be easily identified by the user?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android UUID is set at the first boot

> // Android: Returns a random 64-bit integer (as a string, again!)
>
> //  The integer is generated on the device's first boot

So it's dynamic, won't be written on the device. It's mentioned [here in the docs](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.device)